# Paginated conversations fetching with latest message

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I am trying to create a simple chat application database schema, and query the conversations. My current table setup is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE chat_user (
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    display_name VARCHAR(140),
    ... other user stuff ...
);

CREATE TABLE conversation (
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(140),
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE conversation_message (
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    conversation_id bigint NOT NULL,
    sender_id bigint NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE conversation_participant (
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    conversation_id bigint NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

So basically each conversation has its own title, and multiple participants. What I would like to do is fetch the conversations **paginated, with N conversations on each page** (where a certain user is a participant) sorted by the conversation creation date (or if possible by the date of the latest message). The result set should contain the id, title of the conversation and list of participants (id and display name) + **the id, sender_id and body of the latest message in the conversation**.

What would be the most efficient query to achieve this? Is there maybe some better way to model the schema with the described end goal in mind?

Comment: Post an EXPLAIN ANALYZE for whatever quer(ies/y) you have tried, please?

Comment: First, write the query without pagination, then add `WHERE` and `LIMIT` for keyset pagination. Create the appropriate index for speed.